# How to prevent Notepad++ from reindenting XML

Tags: xml, notepad++

When opening XML in Notepad++, XML is reindented (one node on multiple lines) for readability. But I do not want to as I need to preserve original formatting (one node on single line).

Is there a way a way to prevent it to do so ?

Comment: Really? It doesn't do that for me. Got any plugins installed?

Comment: You're not talking about word wrap, are you? "View" menu -> Word Wrap.

Comment: I just installed latest version 2 days ago so I think I don't have any plugin, and I'm not talking about wordwrap. I think I have pasted some xml in it, save and reload and then it prettify without asking. I'll do it again at work and update the exact manipulation.